# How can I have a "provide a complete, minimal example code that demonstrates the error" with this question?

Tags: discussion, minimal-reproducible-example

With this question, [Why might Eclipse failing to identify fields?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24560946/why-might-eclipse-failing-to-identify-fields), I have been told: "Can you show us complete, minimal example code that demonstrates the error?"

How would I be able to do that on that specific issue? I am unable to duplicate the issue, and giving other people the code is useless since I have already re-copied it into another workspace and I do not get the same issue.

Just to clarify, the issue happens fairly regularly when making new variables, but if I copy-paste the code into another project or workspace, there is never any issue. Therefore I cannot send anything to anybody else that can actually duplicate the issue.

So, is there any way I can actually give a "complete, minimal example code that demonstrates the error"?

Comment: Ask the person who made the comment. Is it necessary to open a meta discussion because one user made a remark? Anyway, I don't think the comment makes sense. The question looks fine to me.

Comment: @Stijn I know that I will get much more informative help on the meta. That said, I understand your point and will attempt to ask the questioner first before posting on the meta in future.

Comment: I think that question would be more suited to the bug tracker of Eclipse.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In this case, an example would consist of a series of steps that are likely to lead to the problem. For example, you could give an initial program, and say how you are creating the new variable. Say what happens when it fails. If the problem is intermittent, you should indicate about how often it happens.

Looking at the question, it appears you have done that.